# jQuery - specify a directory for cycle plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

forget my question for a while... bad choice of words

I am using this code for a jQuery Cycle Slideshow...

script is here... you **may skip** it and proceed to question

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code_snipets/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="code_snipets/jquery_plugin_cycle.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(
   function()
   {
    $('ul#ullist').cycle(
            {
                fx:     'scrollHorz',
                speed:  3000,
                sync:   0,
                prev:   '#prev',
                next:   '#next',
                height: 'auto',
                cleartype:  1,
                timeout: 10000
            }
            );
   }
);
</script>
```

style is here... you **may skip** it and proceed to question

```
ul 
{ 
    display  : block;
    margin   : 0;
    padding  : 0;
    width    : 280px;
    height   : auto;
    overflow : hidden; 
}

ul li 
{ 
    width       : 280px; 
    display     : block; 
    color       : #e0e0e0;
    font-family : Verdana;
    font-size   : 11px;
}
```

html code is here

```
<ul id="ullist2" class="ul_li">
    <li class="ul_li"><img src="images/bu_logo.png"></li>
    <li class="ul_li"><img src="images/bu_title.png"></li>
</ul>
```

now I am using **LIST** for my images... how can suggest a **directory**.. meaning just specify a directory and it should pick all images from directory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this directly...directories aren't returned in a 100% standard fashion from a web server, what happens *usually* is the server in question (*if* directory browsing is enabled) translates the directory to an HTML page with links to the files.

Browsing a directory on IIS vs. Apache vs. nginx, etc will be different, and the plugin doesn't have code to parse all of those responses and pick the image links out.  You could have a server-side handler rendering links in the page based on a directory, but with static HTML the plugin (as it is now) won't do this.